# PHP selected dynamic option with Ternary Operator

Tags: php, ternary-operator

i have this code for select selectbox using Ternory Operator method :

```
Ternary operator let us return one of two values based on a given condition. It’s syntax is like below.

(expression)?(if expression is true):(if expression is false)
```

MyCODE:

```
<select class="form-control contentgroup input-sm" name="access">
<option value="1" <?php echo ($access = 1) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>1</option>
<option value="2" <?php echo ($access = 2) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>2</option>
<option value="3" <?php echo ($access = 3) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>3</option>
</select>
```

but i output i see all option is selected :

```
<select class="form-control contentgroup input-sm" name="access">
<option value="1" selected>1</option>
<option value="2" selected>2</option>
<option value="3" selected>3</option>
</select>
```

how do fix this problem?

Comment: Look at your comparison operation (`=`), it's incorrect.

Comment: change the equal signs in the condition to double equal signs
    ($access == 1) ? 'selected' : '';

Comment: Besides, you don't really need the ternary operator. a simple `if()` is sufficient!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a typo. You are using the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `==` or `===`

```
<option value="1" <?php echo ($access == 1) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>1</option>
<option value="2" <?php echo ($access == 2) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>2</option>
<option value="3" <?php echo ($access == 3) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>3</option>
```

Comment: `+1` Wow... You are so quick!

Comment: That's what she said (-1 from my girlfriend)

Comment: LoL. What? Ha ha... `:P`

Answer (score 0):

Use equivalence operator instead of assignment operator:

```
<option value="1" <?php echo ($access == 1) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>1</option>
<option value="2" <?php echo ($access == 2) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>2</option>
<option value="3" <?php echo ($access == 3) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>3</option>
```

You can either use `==` or `===` while the latter is for strict comparison.